# How to list and delete empty folders on Azure Data Lake Store Gen1

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

#### Question 1:

Is there a way to list and delete empty folders on Azure Data Lake Store Gen 1?

#### Scenario:

We require to periodically run a job to delete all empty folders recursively under a root folder in our data lake storage.

> Folder paths cannot be hard coded as there can be 100 s of empty folders.

#### Question 2:

Can we use Data Factory or Data bricks to perform this operation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rinks.I implemented your requirement with [GetMetadata Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity),If-Condition Activity,For each Activity and Delete Activity. Please see my detailed steps:

Step1, i created 2 empty folders and 1 folder contains one csv file in the root path.

[image]

[image]

Step2, create GetMetadata Activity in the ADF pipeline and output the `childItems`.

[image]

Step3, loop the output by ForEach Activity:`@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`

[image]

***Total structure like:***

[image]

Step4,Inside ForEach Activity,use another GetMetaData Activity and If-condition Activity:

Set the Directory as `@item().name`

[image]

Set the condition expression as `@empty(activity('Get Metadata2').output.childItems)`

***Total structure like:***

[image]

Step5,set Delete Activity as the Failed Activity of For each Activity. Set the `@item.name()` as directory of Delete Activity Dataset.

Test result,`test2` and `test3` folder are deleted:

[image]

[image]

Any concern,pls let me know.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Recursive ForEach (for folders on multiple level) doesn't go well in Data Factory. This has been resolved using Databricks notebook. Details at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/526006aa-f378-4766-9aba-532223a44814/how-to-list-and-delete-empty-folders-on-azure-data-lake-store-gen1?forum=AzureDataLake

Comment: @Rinks Sorry,maybe i provide a complex scenario here.Would you please paste the solution provided by MSFT here which maybe beneficial for other guys on the forum.Really appreciate to you.

Comment: Sure - this is the answer

After mounting in databricks and getting through any permissions issues, one potential (python3) solution:

def recur(item):
  good_to_delete_me = True
  contents = dbutils.fs.ls(item)
  for i in contents:
    if not i.isDir():
      good_to_delete_me = False
    else:
      can_delete_child = recur(i.path)
      good_to_delete_me = good_to_delete_me and can_delete_child
      if can_delete_child:
        test= i.path
        dbutils.fs.rm(test)
  return good_to_delete_me

Answer (score 0):

Answered at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/526006aa-f378-4766-9aba-532223a44814/how-to-list-and-delete-empty-folders-on-azure-data-lake-store-gen1?forum=AzureDataLake

After mounting in databricks and getting through any permissions issues, one potential (python3) solution:

def recur(item):
  good_to_delete_me = True
  contents = dbutils.fs.ls(item)
  for i in contents:
    if not i.isDir():
      good_to_delete_me = False
    else:
      can_delete_child = recur(i.path)
      good_to_delete_me = good_to_delete_me and can_delete_child
      if can_delete_child:
        test= i.path
        dbutils.fs.rm(test)
  return good_to_delete_me